# Flutter http exception '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am trying to get some data with an http get request. This is my code:

```
  Future searchProducts(String search) async {
    var response = await http.get(baseUrl + 'searchProducts');
    var jsonResponse = await convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(jsonResponse['result'].length);
  }
```

Im trying to get a list in the body of the response. When the list gets too large I got this error:

```
E/flutter (12726): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'
```

If I limit the data im getting:

```
I/flutter (12726): 20
```